# Display enum equalivent string values using MVVM

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding, mvvm, enums

My goal is to databind strings that equalivent to my enum.

```
    public enum Language
    {
        Unknown=0,CSharp=1,VB=2,VisualCpp=3,FSharp=4
    }

    public enum ProjectType
    {
        Unknown=0,ConsoleApplication=1,ClassLibrary=2
    }
```

Here's my Model:

```
  class PLanguage
  {
    public Language EnumLanguage { get; set; }
    public string ImagePath { get; set; }
    public List<ProjectType> EnumTypes { get; set; }

  }
```

MyViewModel:

```
  class PLanguageViewModel : ViewModelBase
  {

    public PLanguage PLanguage { get; set; }
    private ObservableCollection<string> _typeCollection;
    public PLanguageViewModel(PLanguage pLanguage)
    {
        PLanguage = pLanguage;
    }
            public ObservableCollection<string> TypeCollection
    {
        get{} //CAST PLanguage.EnumTypes FROM ENUM TO STRING
    }
    public string ImagePath
    {
        get { return PLanguage.ImagePath; }
        set
        {
            if (PLanguage.ImagePath != value)
            {
                PLanguage.ImagePath = value;
                RaisePropertyChanged(() => ImagePath);
            }
        }
    }
    public static String ConvertToString(Enum eEnum)
    {
        return Enum.GetName(eEnum.GetType(), eEnum);
    }

  }
```

As you can see, I have a list of enum of type ProjectType. I want to convert these to an observable collection of strings that equalivent to the enum values, so I can databind them easily in my View.
I need to create a Dependency Property of that collection, how can I do that?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can use [Enum.GetNames](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.enum.getnames.aspx) to get all values and [ObservableCollection constructor overload](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc679169.aspx) for data Binding.

```
public PLanguageViewModel(PLanguage pLanguage)
{
    PLanguage = pLanguage;
    _typeCollection = new ObservableCollection<string>(Enum.GetNames(typeof(ProjectType)));
   ...
}
```

You can use [Enum.Parse](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.enum.parse.aspx) to retrieve the `ProjectType` from observable collection.

**EDIT** as per comment
Use following to bind String to `SelectItem`. Now You can use DataBinding over `SelectedItem` in the view. You can also achieve the same using [IValueConverter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.ivalueconverter.aspx)

```
private ProjectType _selectedItem'

public string SelectedItem
{
   get
    {
      return ConvertEnumToString(_selectedItem);
    }
    set
    {
      _selectedItem = ConvertStringToEnum(value);
    }
}

public static string ConvertEnumToString(Enum eEnum)
{
    return Enum.GetName(eEnum.GetType(), eEnum);
}

public static ProjectType ConvertStringToEnum(string value)
{
    return (ProjectType)Enum.Parse(typeof(ProjectType), value);
}
```

Comment: I see, thank you, how will my Dependency Property of the ObservableCollection will look like?